# React JS : Uncaught TypeError: keeps.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, state, render, setstate

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./components/Input";
import Keep from './components/Keep'

export default function App() {
  const [keeps, setKeeps] = useState(['go','do','make','sleep',])
  let keepsList = keeps.map((keep, id)=>{return <Keep value={keep} key={id} />})
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    setKeeps(...keeps, e)
    console.log(keeps)
  }
  return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Logo">N13G's Keeps</div>
      <Input onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
      <div className="KLmain">
        { keepsList }
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

My kind of analog of Google Keeps doesn't work. It returns an error in a console (keeps.map is not a function).
There's also my Input

```
import React from "react";

function Input ({onSubmit}) {
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  onSubmit(e.target.value)
 }
 return (
 <>
  <form className="Icont" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <input type="text" className="Iinput"/>
   <input type="submit" className="Ibut" placeholder="Add" value={"Add"}/>
  </form>
 </> )
}

export default Input
```

I tried to fix this error by classes, but maybe it's a React bug.

Comment: I guess this is the issue ... `setKeeps(...keeps, e)` you want to set as `setKeeps([...keeps, e])`

Comment: also shouldn't it throw an error when you did `setKeeps(...keeps, e)` 

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your `onSubmit` method:

```
setKeeps([...keeps, e])
```

because you have already set `keeps` as an array. So to set value in `setKeeps` you have to pass an array and to add value into array you can do like this `[...keeps, e]`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `setKeeps(prev => [...prev, e])` instead of `setKeeps(...keeps, e)`. And also use the `keeps.map(...` inside the div tag. I hope this helped you!